# ¿Esta prohibido tener dos cuentas?

Tags: discusión

Acabo de cruzar un par de comentarios con un usuario nuevo ya que he marcado una de sus preguntas como duplicadas y me ha respondido un poco airadamente:

> ¿Me estás cargando? [....] Y está bien aclarado. Leé mejor antes de criticar la pregunta de alguien más.

Sin darle mas importancia, he marcado el comentario para revision y recomendado al usuario visitar el centro de ayuda:

> Hola @Cristian, bienvenido a nuestra comunidad. Te recomiendo que pases por el centro de ayuda y leas detalladamente como formular una buena pregunta, sin olvidar la parte del MVCE y cuando termines pasate por las normas de conducta. Un saludo.

Me ha respondido mal, bastante mal, pero lo que me ha sorprendido ha sido el segundo comentario:

> No. Yo decido como reaccionar ante la incompetencia a mi manera. Si vos tenés aires de grandeza por creerte que sos alguien importante por hacerte el crítico acá, ese es tu problema. La falsa modestia y falsos buenos modales no tapan lo que es evidente a los ojos.

[...]

> Pd: **No soy nuevo acá. Tengo otra cuenta con más reputación que la tuya.** Así que ese comportamiento de creido que tenés no te va a servir de nada acá.

Al rollete ofensivo ya estoy acostumbrado, pero lo de declarar abiertamente que tiene otra cuenta me ha hecho buscar por meta (aunque tiene toda la pinta de ser un mecanismo defensivo):

- [What's the policy about having multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts)
- [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)
- [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

Realmente **NO** esta prohibido por las normas generales tener dos cuentas, siempre que haya un motivo que lo justifique y no se realizen apoyos entre ellas.

Al ser nosotros una comunidad mucho más reducida, ¿esa norma se sigue también en este sitio?

Comment: Desconozco el tema de las 2 cuentas pero está claro que el comportamiento de este usuario no es respetuoso. He marcado los comentarios como inapropiados. Y dudo mucho que tenga otra cuenta con tal reputación... no se puede hacer una pregunta así y tener tanta reputación, es imposible.

Comment: @MiquelColl lo mismo pienso yo, en cuanto al comportamiento y los comentarios... ya habia hecho lo mismo que tú, no pienso entrar al trapo, no vale la pena...

Comment: @JordiCastilla Podrías agregar el vínculo a la pregunta/respuesta donde se originaron los comentarios?

Comment: @devconcept ya han sido eliminados y creo que no es necesario hacer leña con ese tema ni castigar al usuario. Mi pregunta se refiere a tener varias cuentas, con lo que el link a la pregunta no tiene relacion (eso si, no hace falta ser Sherlok Holmes para encontrarla `;)`)

Comment: @JordiCastilla Ya encontré la pregunta referida pero la razón de la petición no es continuar castigando al usuario sino que su mal comportamiento quede registrado para facilitar el trabajo de los moderadores en el futuro si esta situación continúa ya que hay una denuncia oficial. Nuestros moderadores saben que no deben actuar con premura ante usuarios inexpertos pero en este como los demás sitios de Stackoverflow van a existir usuarios con mala actitud y que roban reputación, saber cuales son estas cuentas cuando se producen los hechos ayuda a mantener el sitio saludable.

Comment: definitivamente algo tenemos que hacer: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/684/deber%c3%adamos-castigar-a-usuarios-por-falta-de-buen-comportamiento

Comment: Uhmm, creo que te saliste de tema, si la pregunta era solo para tratar lo de _"...tener 2 cuentas"_ no era necesario detallar acerca de la molestia del usuario y la tuya... pero bueno es mi humilde opinión.

Comment: @x4mp73r lo he puesto para poner contexto, y si te fijas en mis comentarios, siempre he rehusado entrar al detalle y me he intentado centrar en mi pregunta, el tema de la educación está más que tratado y además se ha abierto un post paralelo. Aunque si creéis necesario puedo borrarlo.

Comment: @Rubén arreglado. La próxima vez siéntete libre de editar tu mismo esta u otra pregunta si crees que puedes mejorarla :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla: Aún no tengo el privilegio de editar preguntas en Meta :).

Comment: @Rubén oh! Espero que llegue pronto entonces, de mientras ya esta arreglado :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Punto de vista:

- No está prohibido
- No debería estar prohibido

#### Casos de uso que lo justifican:

Entre otros:

1. Me hice un usuario nuevo porque necesitaba hacer algunas preguntas muy básicas (aunque totalmente válidas) y me daba vergüenza hacerlas con mi usuario "consagrado" porque perdería credibilidad ante otros usuarios que ya me conocen y confían en mis respuestas.
2. Uso una cuenta en mi trabajo para las preguntas referidas a proyectos laborales, mi jefe conoce mi ID y me sigue regularmente... Uso una cuenta personal por placer y no quiero que mi jefe sepa que estoy contestando preguntas no relacionadas a mi trabajo en horario laboral.
3. Tengo una cuenta compartida con mi hermano/socio, que usamos para seguir un proyecto y sus notificaciones... Tengo mi cuenta personal con mis temas.
4. Empecé con 2 usuarios diferentes para sitios diferentes de SE porque no quería cruzarlos (manteniendo notificaciones por separado) y por motivos prácticos terminé superponiéndolos (quizás me interesó votar/comentar en un post de un sitio con el usuario que usaba en el otro), pero rara vez hago un post con el que no quería asignar a un sitio y no me interesa pedir un *merge*.
5. Soy poliglota y muy activo en SE, pero para cuidar mi salud mental hice usuarios diferentes para cada idioma.
6. Tengo un trastorno de identidad disociativo (múltiples personalidades) :)

---

**Nota:** Obviamente los casos de abuso están fuera de discusión y deben ser tratados como tal, ya sea que tenga 1 o varias cuentas (o sean 2 amigos haciendo lo mismo que haría alguien con 2 cuentas o sockpuppets), y preferiría que no se comenten sobre este post ya que lo considero como *no relacionado*.

Comment: Ahora entiendo porque en ocasiones eres cool y otras un insoportable (es broma Mariano: "trastorno de identidad disociativo"). El usuario pudo referirse a otra cuenta en SO en inglés, de cualquier forma el uso incorrecto de una o varias cuentas como la obtención de reputación de una forma fraudulenta o molestar a los integrantes de la comunidad podría ser detectada por los administradores.

Comment: Y a veces estoy loco, pero **sólo a veces** :-)

Answer (score 3):

Concentrado en el tema principal de la pregunta que es si es posible tener más de una cuenta en el sitio, la respuesta es sí, es posible. El tamaño de la comunidad no restringe el número de cuentas que puedes tener. Los motivos por los cuales decidas tener múltiples cuentas son de criterio personal, siempre y cuando sigas las normas respecto a no apoyar una cuenta desde otra para conseguir reputación fraudulentamente.

Comment: Según entiendo el tamaño de la comunidad en los sitios de la red de StackExchange no tiene relación con la política de número de cuentas sino el sentido de la reputación.

Comment: Eso es lo que dice la respuesta. ¿Hay alguna pregunta al respecto?

Comment: Perdón, al leer me salté parte del último enunciado.

Answer (score 2):

## Respuesta corta

Está permitido tener múltiples cuentas siempre y cuenta no haya interacción alguna entre ellas.

## Explicación

Según entiendo, la política sobre el número de cuentas es una política de la red de sitios de Stack Exchange y no una política de un sitio en particular, así que en Stack Overflow en español prevalece, la cual es que no está prohibido tener múltiples cuentas pero debe evitarse toda interacción entre ellas.

Para clarificar, a continuación algunos ejemplos de lo que está permitido, prohibido y recomendaciones para el manejo de múltiples cuentas.

### Permitido

- Publicar preguntas sobre temas distintos
- Publicar respuestas y comentarios en hilos distintos

### Prohibido

- Cualquier interacción entre las cuentas de un mismo usuario como:

  - Votar las publicaciones de las cuentas propias
  - Comentar las publicaciones de las cuentas propias
  - Usar más de una cuenta para participar en un hilo

### Recomendaciones

- Evitar tener más de una cuenta en un mismo sitio y en su defecto evitar participar en las mismas etiquetas
- Evitar publicar contenido similar en sitios distintos usando cuentas distintas
- Evitar citar publicaciones propias realizadas con cuentas distintas
- En caso crear una segunda cuenta accidentalmente, solicitar la fusión de las cuentas.