# Deberíamos castigar a usuarios por falta de buen comportamiento?

Tags: discusión

Estaba tranquilo leyendo `META` cuando el contenido dentro de la siguiente pregunta ([¿Esta prohibido tener dos cuentas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/682/esta-prohibido-tener-dos-cuentas)) me quemó el cerebro. No es mi intención poner leña al fuego, siento que es justo para todos los que andamos por aquí llevarnos y pasarla bien entre preguntas, respuestas, comentarios y conversciones en la sala de chat.

Antes de seguir, vamos citando lo que manda el centro de ayuda de StackOverflow: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

> **La falta de educación y el lenguaje de menosprecio no es correcto.** Tu
> lenguaje debe armonizar con la manera en la que hablas en persona a
> quien respetas y quien deseas que te respete. Si no tienes el tiempo
> de decir algo cortés, déjalo para alguien que sí lo tenga.
>
> **Se acogedor, paciente, y de buenas intenciones.** No esperes que los
> nuevos usuarios conozcan todas las reglas, porque no todos las
> conocerán. Y tenles paciencia en lo que van aprendiendo. Si estás aquí
> para ayudar, hazlo lo más simple posible para que otros también te
> puedan ayudar. Aquí todos somos voluntarios, y nadie responde bien a
> las demandas de ayuda.
>
> **No seas un pelmazo.**
>
> **Apodos/Insultos.** Enfócate en el post, no en la persona. Eso incluye
> términos que se sientan personales incluso cuando sean
> (“perezoso/holgazán”, “ignorante”, o  “quejumbroso”, o “nena”).
>
> **Fanatismo de cualquier tipo.**  Lenguaje que ofenda o aliene a individuos o grupos por motivos de raza, género, orientación sexual,
> religión, etc. no será tolerado. En absoluto. (Son algunos ejemplos,
> en caso de duda, no lo hagas.)
>
> **Lenguaje inapropiado o atención.** Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Evita términos vulgares y cualquier sugestivo
> sexual. Además, este no es un sitio de citas.
>
> **Acoso e intimidación.** Si vez alguna interacción hostil, reportala. Si sigue así, desengánchate, nosotros lo manejaremos. Si alguien
> necesita atención personal, puedes usar el apartado de contacto que se
> encuentra al fondo de la página.

Deberíamos banear temporalmente a un usuario como castigo por el incumplimiento del modelo de ayuda de StackOverflow? Hay alguna otra manera de hacer justicia sobre los estatutos? En caso no hubiera otra manera detallada en el sitio de StackOverflow, qué acciones deberían tomarse? Qué proponen?

Comment: No hay que tomárselo tan personal, como en cualquier foro o similares existen ese tipo de usuarios y como dicen en la respuesta lo correcto es reportarlo.

Comment: Hagamos la paz y no la guerra :P

Comment: como dirían mis brothers de WarCraft: ok makey!

Comment: `No seas un pelmazo.`, ... muy buena.. clap.. clap..

Comment: _Si bien su comportamiento no es aceptable_ estaría de acuerdo que _ya sea un usuario "nuevo" o con mas puntos de experiencia_ considero conveniente usar el baneo _si éste reincide en su comportamiento._ (No tengo la referencia) pero he leído algunas respuestas de un usuario en The Workplace y éste "a pesar de tener reputación en ese sitio", fue colocado en el `water cooler`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es poco complicado que el sitio (u otro) sea 100% aprueba de este tipo de incidencias.

Creo que la respuesta de la comunidad fue adecuada. **Reportarlo de inmediato**

El problema del baneo, es que puede sacar otra cuenta. Y si es baneo por IP, muchos proveedores de internet tienen IP dinamicas por lo cual no es tan efectivo. Aparte de que no se bloquee la IP de una escuela o algo asi, donde se comparte con muchos usuarios.

Como comentaba [Jordi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/517/jordi-castilla), no hechar mas leña al fuego parece lo mejor, para que los usuarios ofensivos no se enganchen contra el sitio
Y las personas que desean ayudar no pierdan su tiempo remediando insultos, y en su lugar puedan aportar cosas positivas.

Pienso que lo mejor es no enfrascarse en una pelea, perderia mas el "buen" usuario.

---

En este post parece que una cuenta troll fue removida del SO [Is it possible to ban a trolling user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278283/is-it-possible-to-ban-a-trolling-user)

Comment: no cabe duda, definitivamente a "Reportarlo de inmediato" y ya :D

Comment: Se podrñia jugar con la reputación negativa. Si un usuario recibe X puntos negativos, de distintas personas, que se le quite temporalmente la cuenta, o pierda los privilegios y se a tratado como un usaurio nuevo. Claro , que el problema sería saber ese valor X

Answer (score 1):

Todos los foros de esta índole deben velar por el cumplimiento de las normas a través de reportes de los usuarios y/o con la colaboración de moderadores para garantizar el bienestar de los usuarios y de la propia plataforma. Las penalizaciones a usuarios tienen sentido cuando el individuo tiene una buena reputación, pero en el caso de usuarios nuevos, robots, o spamers, las penalizaciones deberían de efectuarse en principio por IP (y ojo, que digo en principio).

El problema de bloquear el acceso al sistema a una IP, y como bien opina @fredyfxes, es que en determinadas circunstancias estas operaciones mal intencionadas se realizan en escuelas de ingeniería o centros públicos de interés general, y los bloqueos prolongados a una sola dirección IP puede hacer mucho daño a un gran número de terceros.

Es un tema complejo, y hay que valorar individualmente cada comportamiento para actuar en consecuencia de la gravedad de cada acto específico.