# ¿Es legal tener mas de una cuenta en Stack Overflow y pasarse reputación entre ellas?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, votos

He visto algunos usuarios con el mismo nombre respondiendo sus propias preguntas en sus mismas cuentas, ok no me molesta he visto esto al respecto:

[¿Esta prohibido tener dos cuentas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/682/esta-prohibido-tener-dos-cuentas)

y comprendo que es legitimo tener dos cuentas, pero ahora vamos a otro punto:

Yo siempre busco preguntas las cuales tienen puntuación positiva, la cual debería ser la que tenga una respuesta con más prioridad, pero hoy he visto una pregunta que no tenía mucho sentido con doble puntuación positiva y al mismo tiempo estaba marcada como "tema no relacionado", bueno no es la primera vez... pero, ¿qué opinan al respecto de que los usuarios den reputación falsa a su propia pregunta? ¿No debería ser más legitimo? ¿No se debería prohibir la reputación falsa?

Comment: `He visto algunos usuarios con el mismo nombre respondiendo sus propias preguntas en sus mismas cuentas`... si tienes tal sopecha, puedes hacer un reporte al moderador. Ellos tienen las herramientas para determinar si es el caso que dices o no y tomar las medidas necesarias.

Comment: Para responder a tu propia pregunta no hace falta tener dos cuentas. Incluso existe la opción de hacer una pregunta y antes de publicarla responderla tú mismo. Al fin y al cabo se aprende de una pregunta y su respuesta la haga quien la haga. Yo mismo lo hice una vez porque era un tema que no se había tratado aquí aún, era interesante desde mi punto de vista y prefiero compartirlo que guardármelo para mi. Si haces publicaciones para otorgarte reputación propia te van a pillar y te van a quitar toda esa reputación como ya ha pasado. Es fácil detectar esos patrones automáticamente.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, no es legal tener dos cuentas en Stack Overflow para pasarse reputación entre ellas.

Entendámonos: tener dos (o muchas) cuentas no es ilegal *per se*. Ahora bien, es abuso cuando esta segunda cuenta te permite hacer algo en el sitio que tu primera cuenta no puede hacer. Esto quiere decir votarse, por ejemplo.

En la red Stack Exchange se llama *sockpuppet accounts*. A esto lo podríamos llamar cuentas [títeres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14733/1674), pues básicamente es una misma persona tirando de los hilos de más de una cuenta.

La reputación en Stack Overflow se gana de forma orgánica y en base a la calidad. Usar cualquier otro criterio rompe con esta idea meritocrática.

Referencia oficial:

- [¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1725/83).

Answer (score 10):

Si *alguien* tiene más de una cuenta en el sitio y **además** la utiliza para votarse entre las cuentas (da igual si es unidirección o bidireccional) va a pasar algo muy sencillo:

- La cuenta principal va a ser **suspendida de 7 a 365 días** según la gravedad y la cantidad de veces que se haya suspendido con anterioridad.
- La cuenta secundaria va a ser **eliminada**.

Añadir además que ya existen procesos que detectan este comportamiento y siempre que salta alguna alarma los moderadores investigamos y actuamos.

Para que os hagáis una idea, desde que soy moderador, se han *suspendido+eliminado* más de 15 cuentas de este tipo. Es un comportamiento inaceptable.

Si creéis que os encontráis delante un caso de este estilo no dudéis en levantar un flag personalizado a los moderadores explicando la situación.

Comment: Sinceramente creo que esta es la mejor respuesta que alguien puede dar. No por nada, sino porque es de un propio moderador del sitio que sabe como va realmente todo el sistema. Gracias por añadir info adicional :) Y gracias por estar ahí para que no haya comportamientos de este tipo.

Comment: @Error404 sin quitar ningún mérito a esta respuesta, date cuenta que [es.so] es un sitio dentro de una comunidad que tiene más de ocho años, con sus reglas y demás consensuadas a lo largo del tiempo. Por tanto, no son reglas propias de este sitio sino las globales de la red, que son las que enlazo en mi respuesta. Entiendo pues que esta respuesta explica _qué se hace si se detecta_ (y por parte de un moderador, lo que resulta aún más útil), mientras que la mía explica _porqué_.

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, en ningún momento quería desprestigiar tu respuesta. De hecho, tal y como hice referencia en mi comentario, me refiero al hecho de que explique como va el sistema por detrás (por supuesto hay unas normas y tal, pero hay cosas que a no ser que seamos moderadores no podemos saber). La tuya también me gustó mucho porque hace referencia al sitio oficial. Siento si te ofendí con mi comentario.

Comment: @Error404 faltaría más, hombre :) No me ofendió, solamente consideré oportuno puntualizar la información para que no se prestara a confusión.

Comment: Mi respuesta era complementaria a la de fedorqui que ya cubría el porqué. Simplemente quería añadir información adicional =P