# ¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange?

Tags: discusión, moderación, faq-de-moderadores, cuentas-títere

> Esta es una traducción de [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange) traducida para Spanish Stack Exchange en [¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2602/1674)

Un usuario con alta reputación y mucha actividad había sido llamado la atención por una cuenta [títere](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14733), y le acabo de dar otro aviso. Probablemente tenga otra cuenta títere.

¿Cuáles son las directrices para tratar con los usuarios que se aprovechan del sistema de esta manera? Más específicamente:

- ¿Cómo puedo estar seguro de que me encuentro ante una cuenta títere?
- ¿Cuándo son consideradas un problema las cuentas títere?
- ¿Cómo deben tratar las cuentas títere problemáticas los moderadores, una vez que han sido identificadas?

Y, como usuario, ¿qué acciones puedo o deberían tomarse en caso de ser el dueño o sospechar de cuentas títere?

- He sido suspendido por tener cuentas títere y no creo que sea justo.
- Soy una cuenta títere. ¿Puedo existir si tengo un sentido real?
- Sospecho que hay cuentas títere. ¿Qué debo hacer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### ¿Cómo puedo estar seguro de que estoy ante una cuenta títere?

Nunca se puede estar 100% seguro. Esa que *piensas* que es una cuenta títere, en realidad  puede ser mi amigo Mengano, al que le encanta todo lo que escribo, copia mi estilo al redactar y usa mi ordenador para publicar y votar en cuanto voy a tomarme un café.

Pero en la práctica hay patrones que son extremadamente inusuales, a menos que sea alguien utilizando una segunda cuenta. Si de verdad *es* un amigo muy entusiasta, debería desistir de este comportamiento tras ser apercibido  por ello. Tómate la libertad de contactar al equipo de Stack Exchange si no estás seguro -tenemos bastante experiencia tratando con este tipo de cosas.

### ¿Cuándo son un problema las cuentas títere?

Hay un puñado de razones legítimas para tener múltiples cuentas. Una buena regla básica para detectar títeres abusivos es ésta: **si la segunda cuenta te deja hacer algo que no te está permitido hacer en el sitio con tu cuenta principal, se trata de un abuso**.  Ejemplos de esto incluyen (pero no están limitados a):

- Votar tus propias publicaciones.
- Responder tus propias preguntas con las otras cuentas.
- Votar múltiples veces en las publicaciones de otros.
- Apoyar tus propios argumentos ("*+1" Fulano tiene toda la razón y no sé cómo los demás no os dais cuenta*").
- Usar recompensas (*bounties*) para eludir el límite diario de reputación.
- Eludir suspensiones, prohibiciones o los límites diarios de preguntas / respuestas / comentarios / etc.

¿Por qué es un problema responder a mis propias preguntas con otras cuentas? Porque si aceptas esa respuesta, estarás votando entre cuentas. Además, esa respuesta tendrá más preferencia que una respuesta auto-aceptada (en cuyo caso no aparece arriba del todo por defecto).

### ¿Cómo deben tratar las cuentas títere identificadas los moderadores?

Esto depende del tipo de abuso y de la prudencia del moderador que lo gestiona. Para la primera ocurrencia típica:

- Manda un mensaje a la cuenta principal, y manda otro mensaje a la cuenta secundaria, o bórrala directamente si el abuso es exagerado.

Para ocurrencias posteriores (o para primeras ocurrencias si el abuso es exagerado):

- Suspende la cuenta principal. Borra o suspende las cuentas secundarias.

### Me han suspendido por tener cuentas títere y creo que es injusto; No sabía que esto no estaba permitido / era un compañero de trabajo muy entusiasta / ¡Juro que era mi gemelo malvado Mengano!

Usa esta oportunidad para aprender sobre cómo funciona esta comunidad / habla con tu compañero de trabajo / manda a tu clon malvado de vuelta a la dimensión oscura.

Después asegúrate de que esto no suceda otra vez. Todo el mundo comete errores, y no guardamos ningún tipo de rencor.

#### Has mencionado que hay razones válidas para tener cuentas títere. ¿Cuáles son?

Probablemente habré tenido como media docena de cuentas en este sitio a lo largo del tiempo. A veces son útiles, como para testear bugs que sólo suceden cuando tienes niveles de reputación bajos, recordarte qué impresión causa el sitio cuando sólo tienes los privilegios básicos, [mantener un balance innatural de preguntas/respuestas...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13530/356575) Dicho esto, *siempre* las he tratado como cuentas de usar y tirar, y algunas de ellas *han* sido borradas (de forma automática o por la acción de un moderador) cuando crucé cierta línea en algún momento - Nunca deberías asumir que una cuenta títere está protegida si estás usando múltiples cuentas en este sitio; es demasiado difícil estar seguro de que no estás interactuando de forma inapropiada.

### Soy una cuenta títere. ¿Puedo existir si tengo un sentido real?

> Esta es una traducción de [I am a sockpuppet, may I exist if I have a real purpose?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65604/209901)

Si tienes cuentas títere, muy probablemente encontrarás tus cuentas eliminadas. Si abusas del sistema de votación (votando tus publicaciones de una cuenta desde otra, votando dos veces la misma publicación usando distintas cuentas, dando recompensas de una cuenta a otra, etc.) es muy probable que tus cuentas sean combinadas o eliminadas, así como que tu cuenta principal sea suspendida.

### Sospecho que hay cuentas títere. ¿Qué debo hacer?

Los moderadores disponen de herramientas para detectarlos. Por ello, lo más fácil y limpio es reportar (“flag”) una publicación de ese usuario y, seleccionando la opción “se necesita la intervención de un moderador”, nos comentes tus pesquisas para que lo podamos investigar.

Comment: Observo dos votos negativos. ¿Podríais explicarlos? Más que nada porque esto no deja de ser un FAQ, por ende informativo.