# ¿Qué pasa al combinar o fusionar usuarios?

Tags: soporte, usuarios, cuentas-títere

Tengo *otro* usuario por ahí, que utilizo de vez en cuando. Normalmente, para preguntas o respuestas *chorras*.

Para mi propio asombro, ha conseguido algún que otro voto positivo. Vamos, que ya tiene algunos puntos.

Si relleno el formulario de contacto y solicito *fusionar* las cuentas...

¿Qué pasa con los puntos y medallas de **ambos** usuarios? ¿Se suman ambas, o algo se pierde durante el proceso?

¿Y con los votos que he realizado? No quisiera *perjudicar* a nadie.

Que conste que *apenas* tenemos votos cruzados y/o duplicados. Solo en un par de ocasiones, al principio del *experimento*, para ver qué pasaba.

#### EDITO

Un par de cosillas, **importantísimas**, que quedaron fuera:

- ¿ El proceso es secreto ? ¿ Queda constancia (pública) de que tales o cuales usuarios se fusionaron ?
- Las preguntas / respuestas del usuario *eliminado*, ¿ pasan a ser *propidad* del otro usuario ?
- La cuenta del *absorbido* ¿ se elimina ? ¿ queda con 0 puntos ?

Comment: Por otro lado, es importante destacar que **no está permitido crear distintas cuentas y votarse entre sí**: [¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1725/83). Dices _no quisiera perjudicar a nadie_, pero usar una cuenta para contestar preguntas chorra quiere decir que seguramente esas preguntas no merecían respuesta sino voto de clausura :) Reflexiona al respecto, pues probablemente no esté perjudicando a nadie en particular pero sí a la comunidad.

Comment: La verdad es que nunca lo había pensado así ... tiene su razón. De todas formas, la línea seguida por la comunidad sobre esas preguntas es, digamos ... discontinua. Intentaré contenerme :-) Sobre los votos cruzados, pues fue un *experimento*, a ver que pasaba. Una o dos veces. Y no lo he vuelto a hacer.

Comment: [_Lo siento mucho. Me he equivocado. No volverá a ocurrir_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJvKuYz3zkQ) ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando dos cuentas se unen, le cuenta que queda activa recibe los puntos de la eliminada.  Los votos se reparten y se vuelven a calcular.  Si ha habido votos entre las dos cuentas, esas se eliminan.  Medallas que se hayan ganado no se transfieren a menos de que la cuenta que queda cumple con los requisitos.

Hay otras variables internas pero creo que esto da un resumen apropiado sobre lo que pasa cuando se unen dos cuentas.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y la respuesta. He editado la pregunta, con un par de *cosillas* que se quedaron fuera del tintero. Si no es molestia, ¿ podrías hecharle otro vistazo ?