# ¿Por qué me quitaron 400 puntos de reputación?

Tags: soporte, reputación

No entiendo por qué me descontaron casi la mitad de puntos de reputación que tenia. Tenia 771 puntos y ahora 406... ¿alguien me explica?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Revisando este caso, ciertamente perdiste algunos puntos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La razón: el sistema detecto automaticamente un usuario con "identidad falsa" (sock puppet) y este usuario fue eliminado del sistema; este usuario realizo votación a tu usuario y al eliminarse desafortunadamente elimina la votación que te asigno.

---

> **Sock Puppet**: Cuenta ilegítima en un sistema multiusuario creado por un
>   usuario de "sockupuppeteer" con la intención engañosa de pasar por un
>   tercero inocente que apoya la agenda del sockpuppeteer

Comment: Más información en [¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1725/127)