# Misma pregunta repetida cuatro veces con cambio de usuario

Tags: discusión, revisiones

Hace no mucho tiempo contesté a [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/304663/secuencia-de-tratamiento-de-listas) pregunta a un usuario llamado Carl.

Unos días después vi [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/304887/error-con-listas-en-python) pregunta del mismo usuario y que era básicamente lo mismo, así que la reporté como duplicado como me indicaron en los comentarios.

Poco tiempo después un nuevo colaborador llamado Cristo publicó [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/305699/secuenciador-con-listas-en-python) pregunta, que es exactamente igual que las otras dos. La reporté explicando que era igual para que la cerraran (en los comentarios de la pregunta original indicaba que editase su pregunta en vez de abrir nuevas preguntas iguales).

Hoy he vuelto a ver una pregunta de otro nuevo usuario, esta vez de nombre Mark que es otra vez exactamente igual. La última es [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306124/funciones-con-listas). También la he reportado explicando que es exactamente igual a las otras tres.

Parece que esto no acaba nunca. ¿tengo que seguir reportando las nuevas preguntas exactamente iguales o hay alguna forma de actuar en este caso?, porque parece que va a seguir preguntando una y otra vez lo mismo.

Comment: Vota para cerrar! Para eso está el voto. No entiendo que un moderador lo haya visto y solamente deje un comentario en lugar de cerrar directamente

Comment: Me late que es un usuario que quiere ver qué hace la comunidad en casos así... Que algun mod cierre y bannee las cuentas múltiples :D

Comment: en eso estoy.. yo nunca vi esas preguntas.. :(

Comment: Avisar en meta si no nos dimos cuenta es un gran avance...

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Como reportaba y no pasaba nada, había pensado que igual era yo el que lo estaba haciendo mal... todavía sigo aprendiendo como funciona el sitio!

Comment: Gracias Adrían :D El sitio necesita más usuarios con dedicación a mantener el orden :D

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace En estos casos debes levantar una bandera explicando el problema para que un moderador use sus poderes :-), he visto casos similares en SOen y lo que hacen los moderadores es corroborar si son el mismo usuario y si lo son entonces fusionan las cuentas.

Comment: en la pregunta al lado de cerrar , esta un enlace llamado "reportar", tu le das click alli y di que necesita la intervencion de un moderador y expones los motivos, recuerda que tu tambien eres un moderador; y gracias por reportarlo!

Comment: De seguro debe ser un curso

Comment: @JackNavaRow El enlace de reportar lo utilicé en las preguntas (en todas menos en la original), las dudas me surgieron porque pasaban los días después de haber reportado y no pasaba nada, ni se cerraban las preguntas ni nadie me decía si los reportes eran incorrectos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para no dejar preguntas sin respuesta y que los comentarios sobresalgan, expongo mi opinión:

#### Vota para cerrar como duplicado de la original

Puede que no sea el mismo usuario, sino diferentes personas que atienden el mismo curso. A efectos prácticos, tanto da: lo importante en Stack Overflow son las publicaciones y en ellas nos centramos. Por tanto, si dos preguntas son equivalentes, lo apropiado es marcarlas como duplicadas.

Si además observas que es un mismo usuario y que hay algo importante que se debería hacer por parte de los moderadores y que no puedes hacer tú como usuario, repórtala. Esto incluiría:

- usuarios que han creado [cuentas títere](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1725/83) para eludir bloqueos de pregunta (no parece este el caso, pues un usuario que ha formulado una sola pregunta y esta está abierta no creo que en ningún caso esté bloqueado).
- ...

Lo que sí puede ser útil es utilizar el chat para invocar los votos de cierre, pues cuesta bastante llegar a los cinco votos antes de que alguien responda.